# Alarm keeps firing when I open the app

Tags: android, android-alarms

I create an alarm, it works but the problem is that also after the time I set, the alarm start in the moment I open the application and sometimes, also when is closed and I don't open app. I have this problem since a lot of days, could someone help me?

This is my code:

**ScarsdaleHome.java**

```
public class ScarsdaleHome extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public ScarsdaleHome() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scarsdale_home_activity, container, false);


        Calendar calend = Calendar.getInstance();
        calend.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calend.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calend.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 31);
        calend.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);    

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent,0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calend.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

        return rootView;
    }



    public static ScarsdaleHome newIstance(){
        ScarsdaleHome frag= new ScarsdaleHome();
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {



         Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
         context.startService(service1);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have called the `setRepeating()` method of the `AlarmManager` class, which schedules a repeating alarm that is fired irrespective of whether the user has opened the app or not. If you want to start your `Service` only when the user opens the app, then use

```
alarmManager.set();
```

or

```
alarmManager.setExact();
```

to do so. This will schedule the `Service` to start only when the user opens the app.

**EDIT:**

Define your alarm like this:

```
if(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, 
                           myIntent, 
                           PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null){

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent,0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calend.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

This will not reset the alarm if it is already set.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't want to repeat alarm when I open the app, I only want to show alarm when it is the right time even if the app is closed. My problem is that everytime I open the app , in the precise moment I open ScarsdaleHome , the alarm fires even if the hour is different from the one I have written.